# Way to know the current shell in a given terminal

Tags: unix, shell

I have a shell on a Unix system.

Is there a command that can tell me which shell I am working ? (bash, zsh, etc. )

Comment: I am rushed to post an answer. Have a look [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-what-shell-im-using.html#:~:text=How%20to%20check%20which%20shell,is%20running%20at%20the%20movement.)

Comment: An extensive [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/determine-shell-in-script-during-runtime) was given to question several years ago. It was designed for shell scripts but can be put into a function for interactive shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use environment variables to get the current shell and the shell for the user that is logged in!

`echo $0` - Displays the shell that is currently in use.

`echo $SHELL` - Displays the shell for the user currently logged in.

NOTE: You can use the `printenv` command to look at all the env variables

Comment: `$SHELL` might not be changed if you have started a new shell from your interactive shell.